# Render a byte[] as Bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a byte array from a JNI call, and trying to construct a Bitmap object with it.

My problem is, the following code, returns null.

```
    byte[] image = services.getImageBuffer(1024, 600);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

Any tips about it?

PS: The pixel layout is BGR, not a RGB.

Comment: Have you tested that the image byte array contains the correct content? Otherwise your code looks ok to me.

Comment: Yes, I did. The content is correct, the decodeByteArray that doesn't understood that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decodeByteArray really doens't works with this format. I change from BGR to RGB manually.

```
    byte[] image = services.getImageBuffer(1024, 600);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 600, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i += 3) {
        bmp.setPixel(col++, row, image[i + 2] & image[i + 1] & image[i]);

        if (col == 1024) {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
```

However,

```
for (i < image.length) 。。。bmp.setPixel(image[i + 2] & image[i + 1] & image[i]);
```

can cause:

> 08-29 14:34:23.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8638): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 4):

The doc says the method returns "null if the image could not be decode."
You can try:

```
byte[] image = services.getImageBuffer(1024, 600);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Even if I don't think it's going to change anything though..
Try to have a look at   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options as well

Comment: Same error. And the Options doens't care about the pixel format.